# how to validate a form tab wise, written in multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, tabs

I have divided my form into 3 tabs and and when I click on next button it moves to the next tab and finally in the last tab when submit is clicked the whole form is getting validated which is also correct but my problem is that when I click next it must move to next tab only when the current tab validations are true.

Here is my form

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <form name="registration_form" id="registration_form" action="save.php" method="post">
   <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Basic Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Employee Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Address</a></li>
    </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
      <div class="field">   
        <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />          
        <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
       </div>
       <div class="field">  
         <label>Age</label>
           <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
       </div>
       <div class="field">   
           <input value="Next" type="button" id="next-1" name="1"/> 
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
     <div class="field">   
       <label>Company</label>
         <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
     </div>
     <div class="field">   
       <label>Designation</label>
          <select name="designation" >
            <option value="software developer">software developer</option>
            <option value="software analyst">software analyst</option>
            <option value="tester">tester</option>
           </select>
     </div>
     <div class="field">   
      <label>Annual income</label>
        <input type="text" name="income" id="income"> in Rupees
    </div>
    <div class="field">   
       <input value="Next" type="button" id="next-2" name="2" /> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
     <div class="field">   
       <label>Address</label>
         <input type="text" name="address" id="address" 
     </div>
    <div class="field">   
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="reg_submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

**Javascript Validation code** is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    var validator = $("#registration_form").validate({ rules: {
                first_name: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength:30,
                },
                last_name: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength:30,
                },
                age: {
                    digits:true,
                },
                company: {
                    required: true,
                },
                designation: {
                    required: true,
                },
                income: {
                    digits:true,
                },
                address: {
                    maxlength:100,
                },
                },
            messages: {
                first_name: {
                    required: "Please enter First Name",
                    maxlength: "maximum 30 characters are allowed",
                },
                last_name: {
                    required: "Please enter Last Name",
                    maxlength: "maximum 30 characters are allowed",
                },  
                age: {
                    digits: "Enter only digits",
                },
                Company: {
                    required: "Please enter Company",
                },
                designation: {
                    required: "Please Select Designation",
                },
                income: {
                    digits: "Enter only digits",
                },
                address: {
                    maxlength: "Maximum of 100 characters are allowed",
                 },
                 }
                });
```

// I have seen some examples in stack overflow and tried as below, but it is not working

```
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
       $('[id^=next-]').click(function() {
       var tabid = $(this).attr('name');
       var valid = true;
       var i = 0;
       var $inputs = $(this).children("div").find("input");

       $inputs.each(function() {
       if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
        validator.focusInvalid();
        valid = false;
       }
       });

       if (valid) {
       var tabId = $(this).attr('name');
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", tabId );
       }
       });

       $("input[id=reg_submit]").click(function() {
       $(this).parents("form").submit();
       });
```

please help,
Thanks

Comment: Make three forms. For tab1, tab2 and tab3

Comment: I don't want to divide it into 3 forms. I want to do it in single form. internal forms don't work for HTML

Answer (score 2):

```
var next1 = false;
var next2 = false;
var next3 = false;

$('#next-1').on('click', function(){
     //validate your inputs fields

     var next1 = true;// assign true if validation is correct.
});

$('#next-2').on('click', function(){
//validate your inputs fields

     var next2 = true;// assign true if validation is correct
});

$('#next-3').on('click', function(){
//validate your inputs fields

        var next3 = true;// assign true if validation is correct

                if((next1 == 'true') && (next2 == 'true') && (next3 == 'true'))

                        {
                                 //submit form
                        }

})
```

try this example

Or Make three forms,

Comment: can you please give the complete code which comes in the place where you have written comment //validate your input fields  @prashant

Comment: @rjirji : google dude. your problem is not validation. your problem  was logic which is in answer. http://contactmetrics.com/blog/validate-contact-form-jquery, http://www.formget.com/jquery-contact-form/